# CSS select an element with no certain child element

Tags: html, css

For example we have this

```
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p><img src="" /></p>
<p></p>
```

How can we select all p elements and apply css styles into it except those with img child element?

Comment: You can provide ids to all the elements. And then select the wanted ones.

Comment: Give all of the elements you want to apply css to a class attribute: `<p class='NAME'></p>` and then reference the class in css like so: `.NAME { [css code] }`

Comment: I actually am selecting p tags inside a wysiwyg editor in wordpress but except those p with img on. cause by default all texts/images in wysiwyg editor will be wrapped up in p tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

css `:not()` not supported to select except "has element" but you can do it with jQuery

```js
$('p').not(":has(img)").css('background-color', 'yellow')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>aa</p>
<p>aa</p>
<p>img<img src="" /></p>
<p>aa</p>
```

Comment: wordpress admin has jQuery so why not, this is better than nothing

Comment: Question from future... what if there is no jQuery?

Comment: Behind Flag in Chrome 101, and full support in chrome 105+..
p:not(:has(img)) { background-color: yellow; }

Answer (score 3):

> How can we select all `<p>` elements and apply CSS styles into it except those with `<img>` child element?

#### CSS cannot look "down" (or "ahead").

In other words, you cannot write a selector which depends on anything **following** the element you want to select.

There are many proposals for so-called "parent selectors", or `:contains`-type CSS syntax, but these are far from being approved, much less implemented.

There are work-arounds for individual situations which you can find via appropriate Google/SO searches. For example, if it is possible to take the `img` tag OUT of the `<p>` and move it in front of the `<p>`, then you could probably accomplish what you want using sibling combinators such as `+` and `~`. Or, if absolutely necessary, you can write some JavaScript code.

Comment: Soon you can in Chrome 105+, with selector :has()..

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late to answer. But lately, I found myself in OP's situation and stumbled upon this question. None of the answers on web satisfied me. So, I found one myself, here it is.

My need was to have all `p` tags with width `700px` except the ones having `img` as a child. In my case, I wanted those `p` tags with `img` child to have `1000px` width. So, I defined the following classes in my CSS file.

```
.post-full-content p {
    max-width: 700px;
}

.post-full-content-img {
    max-width: 1000px !important;
}
```

Then I added the following JS,

```
window.onload = function () {
    var ptags = document.querySelectorAll('p');
    // Adding max width to the images
    for (var i = 0; i < ptags.length; i++) {
        if (ptags[i].firstElementChild && ptags[i].firstElementChild.tagName === 'IMG') {
            ptags[i].className += ' post-full-content-img';
        };
    }
}
```

Hence upon page load, `p` tags with `img` child will get an additional class that'll be responsible for a different style. By slightly altering the code I've provided, I hope you'll be able to achieve what you want.